# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: html, innerhtml, countdown

The countdown can't appear on the website as below.

[image]

When I input the codes here, the result is appear the countdown.

[image: in stack]

But I don't know why in my browser (chrome & IE) it doesn't appear, just zero as picture above.

[image: in Chrome and IE]

PLease find the code here:
https://pastecode.io/s/sgkfae0y

Thanks.

```js
let daysItem = document.querySelector("#days");
let hoursItem = document.querySelector("#hours");
let minItem = document.querySelector("#min");
let secItem = document.querySelector("#sec");

let countDown = () => {
    let futureDate = new Date("17 Dec 2021");
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let myDate = futureDate - currentDate;
    //console.log(myDate);

    let days = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    let hours = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
    let min = Math.floor(myDate / 1000 / 60) % 60;
    let sec = Math.floor(myDate / 1000) % 60;

    daysItem.innerHTML = days;
    hoursItem.inneraHTML = hours;
    minItem.innerHTML = min;
    secItem.innerHTML = sec;
}

countDown()

setInterval(countDown, 1000)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Handlee&family=Merienda&family=Nova+Oval&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
 }

 h1 {
    color: rgb(240, 51, 139);
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
}

.nama-mempelai {
    font-family: 'Nova Oval', cursive;
}

h2 {
    color: grey;
}

p {
    font-size: 125%;
}

 .container {
     display: absolute;

 }

 .countdown {
    margin: 60px auto 10px auto ;
 }

 .countdown-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(255, 155, 172);
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }


.box-countdown {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 2px solid rgb(250, 116, 138);
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgb(117, 117, 117, 0.5);
    max-width: 150px;
    display: block;
    padding: auto 20px;
}

.big-text {
    font-size: 4rem;

}

.profil-mempelai {
    margin: 60px auto 10px auto ;
 }

.profil-mempelai-container {
    display: flex;
    color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.box-profil {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px 50px ;
    border: 2px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px rgb(117, 117, 117, 0.5);
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 230px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}

.judul-section {
    margin: 20px;
}
 footer {
    padding: 20px;
    color: rgb(56, 55, 55);
    background-color: #ff0ea3
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
    <title>Nama kedua mempelai</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top">
                <h2>Wedding Invitation</h2>
                <h1 class="nama-mempelai">Yestria & Bima</h1>
                <h3>17 December 2021</h3>
                <p class="ayat"><i>"Dan di antara tanda-tanda (Kebesaran)-Nya ialah Dia menciptakan pasangan-pasangan untukmu dari jenismu sendiri, agar kamu cenderung dan merasa tentram kepadanya dan Dia menjadikan di antaramu rasa kasih dan sayang. Sungguh pada yang demikian itu benar-benar terdapat tanda-tanda (Kebesaran Allah) bagi kaum yang berpikir."</i>
                    <br>(QS. Ar-Rum : 21)</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="countdown">
                <h1 class="judul-section">Countdown of Our Wedding</h1>            
                <div class="countdown-container">
                    <div class="box-countdown">
                        <div id="days" class="big-text">0</div>
                        <span>Days</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-countdown">
                        <div id="hours" class="big-text">0</div>
                        <span>Hours</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-countdown">
                        <div id="min" class="big-text">0</div>
                        <span>Minutes<span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-countdown">
                        <div id="sec"a class="big-text">0</div>
                        <span>Seconds</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="profil-mempelai">
                <h1>The Start of A New Journey</h1>    
                <div class="profil-mempelai-container">
                    <div class="box-profil">
                        <img src="akhwat.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
                        <h2 class="nama-mempelai-1">Yestria Yaswari</h2><p><b>Daughter of</b><br>Mr. Father & Mrs. Mother</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box-profil">
                        <img src="ikhwan.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                        <h2 class="nama-mempelai-2">Bimo</h2><p><b>Son of</b><br>Mr. Father & Mrs. Mother</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <h1>Gallery</h1>
            <div class="gallery">

            </div> 
            
            <h1>Best Wishes for Yestria & Bimo</h1>
        </div>
     

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to add a [mcve] (as _text_) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: hi, ivar. I've insert the link of code since I can't copy to this posting. Please help.

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works I'm afraid. Have a look at [ask]. The code should be as a [mcve] as text in the question itself, not behind a link. Be sure to include the HTML here as well (including where this script is inserted into the page and the elements/tags you are referencing), as that is very relevant here.

Comment: i've tried to insert the code here but there's error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: hi, ivan. I've succed to insert the codes here. please kindly check my revised question. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element You are trying to find/query the element before it exists.

Answer (score 0):

`hoursItem.inneraHTML` is surely incorrect, you need to fix it to `hoursItem.innerHTML`.

The error message tells you that there is no `innerHTML` of `null`, so you have an unidentified variable whose member you intend to refer. This causes the error. It seems that your code chunk does not contain the position of your actual error.